# How to get data from a LongListSelector item in WP8

Tags: c#, windows, mvvm, windows-phone-8

So I have a LongListSelector that will soon be bound to a list of object.

What I want is when one of the LongListSelectorItems is tapped that I get the specific object tapped, and have the ability to pass that object to another screen so I can show full information about the object

```
private void PeopleList_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS");
    }
```

My Tap is working, I just don't know how to get the object that was selected, or how to pass it to another page using NavigationService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SelectionChanged` event and `LongListSelector.SelectedItem` property to get selected item.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try this out!
How can I pass this object to another page?

Comment: @bam2403 one way to do it is to have a global variable for the selected object that you can populate when the Tap or SelectionChanged event is fired.  Then when you navigate it to the next page, you can access that global variable.

Answer (score 3):

Below is pulled straight from my latest app.

You can't directly pass an object, but you can pass text data. In my case, an id:

```
private void WishListBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (WishListBox != null && WishListBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var selectedItem = (Models.Gift)WishListBox.SelectedItem;
        WishListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        var id = selectedItem.Id;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Gift/GiftView.xaml?action=load&id=" + id, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

then on the receiving end:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("action"))
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString["action"]=="load")
        {
            PageTitle.Text = "edit gift";
            giftVm.Gift = App._context.Gifts.Single(g => g.Id == Int32.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["id"]));                    
        }
        else if (NavigationContext.QueryString["action"] == "new")
        {
            PageTitle.Text = "new gift";
        }
        else if (NavigationContext.QueryString["action"] == "newWishList")
        {
            App.vm = ((MainViewModel)App.vm).Me;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey('action') is false");
    }
}
```

In my case, the data is stored in a DB. I simply cast the selected item to the correct object type, then check its ID and pass that to the next page where I do a lookup.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What if i get the data from web api ? How should i change the code ?

Comment: the line:
giftVm.Gift = App._context.Gifts.Single(g => g.Id == Int32.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["id"]));

is where I look up the record in the database and assign it to my ViewModel. You would likely change this line to call the API and handle it's response.