# How to get text from long list selector item in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a long list selector that is populated dynamically meaning the user adds items there.
This is the way items are added.

```
source.Add(new ShoppingList(Item1.Text));
```

Item1 is a textbox via which user adds stuff to the list.

I have a long list selector.  Let's call it LLS.  I want that when a certain itam is tapped, the text within the item is copied and pasted into a textblock.

So far I have tried the following:

```
string item = LLS.SelectedItems.ToString();  TextBlock.Text = item;
```

How can this be achieved?
Thank You for your attention and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ShoppingList sitem = LLS.SelectedItem as ShoppingList;
string item = string.empty;
if ( sitem != null )
{
 item = sitem. (property where you text is stored)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to subscribe to SelectionChanged Event:

```
private void LLS_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (LLS.SelectedItem != null)
  {
     ShoppingList item = LLS.SelectedItem as ShoppingList;
     TextBlock.Text = item.yourProperty;
  }
}
```

BTW - there are already similar questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033135/get-the-index-of-the-selected-item-in-longlistselector), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898270/how-to-get-data-from-a-longlistselector-item-in-wp8) and probably more.

Comment: Sorry i am kind of a noob in programming, so exactly what do you mean by "yourProperty"

Comment: ShoppingList is your class, and by meaning yourProperty I mean the variable/property where you hold text. When you run new ShoppingList(item.text) - that's the name of the variable where item.text was stored.